# PEAR::DB Error, Extension Not Found

Tags: php, mysql, pear

I am attempting to install phpBugTracker on our web server.  When I attempt to test the database connection on the installation screen, I get an error screen that reads "DB Test Failure... DB Error: extension not found".  The error is being thrown from the following function:

```
function test_database(&$params, $testonly = false) {
    // PEAR::DB
    define('PEAR_PATH', ''); // Set this to '/some/path/' to not use system-wide PEAR
    // define('PEAR_PATH', 'inc/pear/'); // use a locally installed Pear (phpBT v0.9.1)
    if (!@include_once(PEAR_PATH.'DB.php')) {
        $error_message = translate("Failed loading Pear:DB");
        $error_info = translate("Please check your Pear installation and the defined PEAR_PATH in install.php");
        $error_info .= " <a href='http://pear.php.net/'>http://pear.php.net/</a>";
        include('templates/default/install-dbfailure.html');
        exit;
    }
    // execution gets this far without a problem...
    $dsn = array(
        'phptype' => $params['db_type'],
        'hostspec' => $params['db_host'],
        'database'  => $params['db_database'],
        'username'  => $params['db_user'],
        'password'  => $params['db_pass']
        );
    $db = DB::Connect($dsn);

    // Simple error checking on returned DB object to check connection to db
    if (DB::isError($db)) {
       // $db go boom...
        $error_message = isset($db->message) ? $db->message : '';
        $error_info = isset($db->user_info) ? $db->user_info : '';
        include('templates/default/install-dbfailure.html');
        exit;
    } else {
        if ($testonly) {
            include('templates/default/install-dbsuccess.html');
            exit;
        } else {
            return $db;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using MySQL version 5.0.45, PHP version 4.47, and I have PEAR::DB version 1.7.6 stable.  I've already verified that I can connect to the database I'm using with the login I've created otherwise.  I am at the mercy of my hosting company as to what modules are installed.

Any ideas on what could be causing the error?

**Edit:** *db_type* is set to "mysqli".  When I use "mysql" as the type I get a "connection failed" error instead.

Comment: mysql  -> MySQL (for MySQL <= 4.0)
mysqli -> MySQL (for MySQL >= 4.1) (requires PHP 5) (since DB 1.6.3)

https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db.intro-dsn.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I feel rather silly, but the path to MySQL was different on this particular server and I had just assumed localhost.  This had nothing to do mysql vs. mysqli.  Fixed path and it connected just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Verify with phpinfo() that extension for `db_type` you're using is installed and activated.
Perhaps you're trying with "**mysqli**" `db_type`, while you should use "**mysql**" 
**(without 'i')**?

MySQL**i** doesn't come by default with PHP4.

Comment: When I try using "mysql" instead of "mysqli" I get a "connect failed" error instead.

Comment: Ahhhh - I did not know that.  I think my server can use either version, I'll have to try under version 5.x